# I have to restart my whole EC2 server any time I change PHP settings

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I've set up a really basic EC2 instance with phpMyAdmin, 100% identically to [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).

I encounter this issue all the time but this time it's really grating. Any change to php.ini or any other php-related settings gets completely ignored unless I reboot the whole instance. Restarting Apache does nothing, I can't think of what else to do.

I get that this question is somewhat vague, but does anyone know why this would be the case?

Comment: what is the instance.type you are using?

Comment: It's just a stock-standard Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue when I use t2.micro or t2.medium too
The memory available is too low for these instance-types.

Please try to upgrade your instance hopefully that problem will go away